# How can I get to UIToolbar of the current view

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitoolbar

I have a navigation controller based app, and added some toolbar items with code in `viewDidLoad:`

```
NSArray* toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                         [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd 
                                                                       target:self
                                                                       action:@selector(addButton)],
                         [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace 
                                                                       target:self
                                                                       action:nil],
                         [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCompose 
                                                                       target:self
                                                                       action:@selector(composeMail)],
                         nil];
[toolbarItems makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(release)];
self.toolbarItems = toolbarItems;
```

now I want to show an actionSheet with `[UIActionSheet showFromToolbar:]` and I want a **UIToolbar *** for that, how can I get the UIToolbar that I have created earlier?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you mean "of the current view controller." In that case you want `self.navigationController.toolbar`.

Comment: This is also assuming the view controller is added to a `UINavigationController`.

If the toolbar was added to the view itself they would need to add an outlet to their view controller and connect it wouldn't they?

Comment: The OP indicated "I have a navigation controller based app." Yes, if you manually manage your own toolbar, then you have to keep track of it in the same way a nav controller does.

Comment: toolBar is added only with the code I wrote, in `viewDidLoad` of RootViewController.m. No Outlet connection.

Comment: Used `self.navigationController.toolbar`, error:
Property 'toolbar' not found on object of type 'UINavigationItem *'

Comment: Are you sure you didn't type `self.navigationItem.toolbar`, perhaps using autocomplete?